# Delegate Event didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not called if select a movie?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

i want to use a UIImagePickerController. If i select a picture from the PhotoLibrary, it´s all ok, the method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is called. But if i select a movie, the movie opens. If i select the "choose" Button, the method didn´t called. Can anyone help me? I use Xcode 4.0.2 and iOS 4.3.2

Thank You

Comment: did you set the mediaTypes to include kUTTypeMovie ?

Comment: i try three different mediaTypes:
1.[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
2. @"public.movie"
and 3. kUTTypeMovie

Comment: and nothing works!!! i also tried the sourcecode of the Apple Developer Library but no success.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    if([[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"] isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
        //something code
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```